# wireguard - restrict routing in wg subnet for specific client

Tags: ufw, wireguard

I need to restrict access of specific client in wireguard subnet to other clients except one in this subnet.

By default, client can send packets to each other.

Here's postUp and postDown settings for my wireguard server .conf file:

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $5; exit}'` -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip rule add from `ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet" | grep -v "inet6" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'` table main
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o `ip route | awk '/default/ {print $5; exit}'` -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip rule del from `ip addr show $(ip route | awk '/default/ { print $5 }') | grep "inet" | grep -v "inet6" | head -n 1 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'` table main
```

The first one turns into something like `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`.

The second one turns into `ip rule add from 95.93.92.116 table main`.

The setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The selected client (net `10.11.12.0/24`), for example, `10.11.12.4` need to get access to `10.11.12.3`, but be restricted for every other client in this net.

Using ufw doesn't help. When I set rule:

```
ufw route deny from 10.11.12.4 to 10.11.12.0/24
```

or even

```
ufw deny from 10.11.12.4 to any
```

Client still can ping and have access to services in subnet.

How can I restrict access of `10.11.12.4` to `10.11.12.3` only?

Comment: Please share what kind of restrictions are required.

Comment: @Turdie Client should not connect to services, running on other machines in wireguard network, such as Grafana, SQL servers etc. except one machine. I can edit client's .conf file in "allowedIPs" setting, but this is considered as unsafe, because client can modify its file to grant access to whole network.